# GridFS support in Grails GORM for Mongo RC1?

Tags: grails, plugins, mongodb, grails-orm

Does anyone know if the latest Grails GORM for Mongo plugin supports GridFS?? Looked at the docs but couldn't find any information? If so please may you provide an example.

Comment: Is this still the case?

Answer (score 0):

No, no support yet. You can create a feature request at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB